# How to query term_id of a Custom Taxonomy by name

Tags: customization, taxonomy, query

I have created a custom taxonomy "Birthday" within which i have created various dates like "December-12", "April-15"

How to get the term_id of the "December-12" by a query.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll want to create a [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) and use `tax_query` -- If you a little more direction I can help you write the query. However I'm not sure your final uses for this so I may not be able to answer it completely without further input.

Comment: To use with the below function:

$users = get_objects_in_term( $term_id, $term->taxonomy );

I want to get the $term_id ( id of "December-12" created under "Birthday")

rather than using $term_id = get_queried_object_id();

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`get_term_by`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) function. This allows you to obtain a term (from a given taxonomy) by its slug or name (or id). The returned term object contains the term's ID.

For example:

```
$term =get_term_by( 'name', 'December-12', 'Birthday');
$term_id = $term->term_id;
```

If 'December-12' is the slug, rather than the name, of the term, simply replace 'name' with 'slug'.

Comment: Thanks, i also figured out another way, i am not sure if its a clean code thought.. :-)

<?php

$categories = get_categories(array( 'taxonomy' => 'birthday' ));
foreach( $categories as $category ) { 
$category_name = $category->name;
$category_id = $category->cat_ID;
$todays_date = date("F-d");


 if ($category_name == $todays_date) {

 
$users = get_objects_in_term( $category_id, 'birthday' );

?>

Comment: That would do it - but its less efficient and my answer only takes two lines :D. Its also more complicated to read.